# making an inner div appear further from top

Tags: css, html, positioning

I'm trying to make the inner div appear further down the page, but it just sits at the top with what looks like the default margin of the outer div #top_middle

```
<div id="top_center">
   <div id="main_container"></div>
</div>

#top_middle
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 0px
}
#main_container
{
    width: 800px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ddd093;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give **position:absolute** to this div. Since top value works with position (absolute, relative) only ...

```
#main_container
    {
    width: 800px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #ddd093;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute
    }
```

Comment: Thank you the top now works but now it is not centered. I tried adding height to the #top_middle thinking its getting pushed out because their isn't enough room in the div, but no go still.

Answer (score 0):

Add position:absolute in thid css

```
#main_container{
...;
position:absolute;
...
}
```